# Can radiation from an accelerated free charge particle be quantised in-terms of photons?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, electromagnetism, quantum-field-theory, classical-mechanics, photons

Over last few days I have been overwhelmed by the following riddle or maybe a simple misunderstanding.

A free particles does not possess quantised energy levels and the entire energy of it can be accounted for its kinetic energy, which is of course, continuous. In any other example of radiation, it’s almost always the motion of bound electrons (harmonic/bound) which leads radiation. However, in case of a free particle does not commence any bound motion rather continuous motion, so can the consequent radiation be quantised in-terms of wave-packets or photons ?

It could be a horrible misconception from my end hence any rectification or guidance on this will be warmly appreciated and greeted.

Thanks.

Comment: [Bremsstrahlung](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bremsstrahlung) does not involve bound electrons, and can be described in terms of photons.

Comment: Are you asking us to correct your text for you ?

Comment: An accelerated charge is not "a free particle". It is not a bound quantum state, but that does not mean that it can't exchange energy with the electromagnetic field. Think of the two charges as a radiating dipole. Since all such energy exchanges are quantized because the em field is a quantum field, Bremsstrahlung emissions also have to be quantized.

Answer (score 0):

No. The quantization of light has nothing to do with the electron's quantized energy levels when it's bounded.

So, if the electron is free, the quantization of light would still hold true - and your question seems to ask where quantization of light idea comes from in the first place. Well, there's the photoelectric effect, Compton scattering (light waves shift in frequency, and bounce off at an angle - that's mediated not by its "wave" property, but by its "particle" scattering behavior).

Comment: Quantization of the free em field is not a function of the existence of bound systems with discrete energy levels. It is a much more general phenomenon. The universe seems to be unable to exchange any energy unless there is also a discrete change of angular momentum happening.

Answer (score 0):

A moving free charge is subject to acceleration when passing through a magnetic field. In the process, the charge emits quantised energy packets.

In a particle accelerator, electromagnetic radiation in the form of photons is therefore emitted behind each deflecting magnet - sometimes desired and sometimes just annoying.

The most extreme form of such photon generation occurs in a free-electron laser, in which the electrons lose their kinetic energy when emitting photons between periodically alternating magnetic field directions.